# Connecting S3 Buckets to Apache Hive and PrestoDB

Tags: amazon-s3, hive

I am connecting S3 Buckets to Apache Hive so that I can query the `Parquet` files in S3 directly through [PrestoDB](https://prestodb.io/).

For this, I configured the `hive-site.xml` file and added my AWS Access Key and Secret Key in the file, as mentioned in [this blog post](http://blog.danielcorin.com/code/2016/04/11/querying-s3-with-presto.html). Now, my S3 Bucket URL path where `Parquet` files reside looks like:

```
https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/sb.mycompany.com/someFolder/anotherFolder/?region=us-east-2&tab=overview
```

While Create an external table, I gave the location for S3 as:

```
LOCATION "s3://sb.mycompany.com/someFolder/anotherFolder"
```

The Apache Hive **isn't able to find the parquet files at the mentioned location** as it is not returning any data to the queries. This folder contains multiple parquet files. My question:

- Can Hive collect data from all parquet files at once as they all have
  the same schema as I defined for my external table?
- Is the S3 Location I specified is in correct format or should I include the region for S3 bucket as well (if yes, how)?

Comment: Did you found the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you data is partitioned you need to repair the table, in some cases even you dont have any partitions you must repair the table, use the following command in hive:

set hive.msck.path.validation=ignore;

msck repair table schema.table;